# Self.revealViewController() returns nil

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am currently trying to get the pan gesture to reveal the controller. As of right now, my open button works, but when I add the last line, my program crashes because revealViewController is nil. Link to pod: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController.

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    class MainViewController : UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        mainButton.makeCircle();
        Open.target = self.revealViewController()
        Open.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:));
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely you haven't set your `SWRevealViewController` to be the `rootViewController`. Remember to set **Custom Class** and **Storyboard ID** to be `SWRevealViewController` in your **Identity inspector**.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")    
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = rootVC

    // Cont. with your code...
}
```

---

In case you need to show a login page at the beginning, you need a function in you `AppDelegate`, which allows the window to update the `rootViewController`

```
func changeRootVCToSWRevealVC () {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
    if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = rootVC
    }
}
```

After user logged in, you can change the `rooViewController` to `SWRevealViewController`.

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.changeRootVCToSWRevealVC()
}
```

If you have a variable storing the state of the last log-in, and want to navigate directly to the Navigation Drawer menu rather than `LoginViewController`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let rootVCId = isLoggedin ? "SWRevealViewController" : "LoginViewController"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: rootVCId)    
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = rootVC

    // Cont. with your code...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but where do I put this? Im assuming its the app delegate but I already have another root view controller for user login; thus letting the app crash. Is there a  fix or am i putting it in the wrong place? Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have a variable storing the state of last log-in, and want to navigate directly to the Navigation Drawer menu rather than forcing user to re-login, you can modify the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to check whether the `rootViewController` should be `LoginViewController` or `SWRevelViewController`.

Comment: @Lawliet I have tried your code but its not working for me I am also using SWRevealViewController only

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same issue and came across this post. My issue turned out to be more of an "oops!" as I missed something obvious and spent 30 minutes scratching my head on it. :facepalm:

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, check to make sure you connected your menu property to the storyboard with an outlet.

Swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if (self.revealViewController() != nil) {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    }
}
```