# How to Skip login if user logged already in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, appdelegate

[image][image]To skip login if user logged already I am using user defaults and in app delegate I am calling home view controller but the problem is the data is not getting as error coming as nil error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swreal view controller`

here my code

```
 if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "login") {
        //YES Already Login

        self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
                    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        //NOT Login
        self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signinpage") as! ViewController
                    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
                    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

and after skiped login to home nil value appearing in this 3rd line. self.view......

```
super.viewDidLoad()
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

 @IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you Sure You want to Logout", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signinpage") as! ViewController
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "login")
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([secondViewController], animated: true)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



}
```

Comment: show us code for `HomeViewController` how are u instantiating `SWRevealViewController` in `HomeViewController` etc etc

Comment: @sandeep please check my question is updated and only those 3 lines in view did load and logout action

Comment: is `menuButton` an IBOutlet?? how is `menuButton` being initialised??

Comment: @ Sandeep yes     @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

Comment: Error you posted does not indicate the issue is in third line of your code, I believe its the issue in `SWRevealViewController` can u post the code for it??

Comment: which code its 3rd party application as I imported in to my application i.e., SWRevealViewContriller .h and .m files

Comment: @ Sandeep can I send those files ?

Comment: I think there are couple of threads discussing similar issue with SwRevealViewController, try checking that else leave a comment on their GitHub page IO haven't used it so I don't have clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

First check your **storyboard Id**, is that proper or not. And you can check below code for more information. Hope that it may help to solve your problem.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "login") != nil {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let viewController: HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
                    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! NavigationController
                    navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
                    mainViewController.rootViewController = navigationController
                    let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!
                    window!.rootViewController = mainViewController
                    UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: nil, completion: nil)
                }
        }
```

Comment: my identifier "HomeViewController" is correct and can you explain me these lines bcz I don't have Main and Navigation controllers as error showing as Use of undeclared type 'MainViewController' and Use of undeclared type 'NavigationController'

Comment: I am following LGSideMenu Approach. You can find below link for more understanding. It will clear your confusion.
[https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController]

Comment: @ Jayakar LgSidemenu is nice but my app is completely designed and at last I found this issue as user already logged it should go to home page or else I us that only

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     // Override point for customization after application launch.

     //Check that user login or not        
     if let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "login") as? Bool {

        //If already login then show Dashboard screen    
        self.showDashboardScreen()
     } else {

        //If not login then show Login screen
        self.showLoginScreen()
     }

     return true 
}

func showLoginScreen() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginViewController: LoginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "#LoginViewControllerStoryboardID") as! LoginViewController

     var navigationController = UINavigationController()
     navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)

     //It removes all view controllers from the navigation controller then sets the new root view controller and it pops.
     window?.rootViewController = navigationController

     //Navigation bar is hidden
     navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true 
}

func showDashboardScreen() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let dashboardViewController: DashboardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "#DashboardViewControllerStoryboardID") as! DashboardViewController

     var navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardViewController)

     //It removes all view controllers from the navigation controller then sets the new root view controller and it pops.
     window?.rootViewController = navigationController

     //Navigation bar is hidden
     navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my observation, 
`self.revealViewController()` is nil. To assure if this is nil, add a breakpoint at the 3rd line and print self.revealViewController() in the console by doing

```
po self.revealViewController()
```

if that is nil, 
Refer below links:

[Self.revealViewController() returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045115/self-revealviewcontroller-returns-nil)

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/627

https://www.codebeaulieu.com/programming/2017/5/5/a-cleaner-swrevealviewcontroller-implementation-using-swift-extensions

Also, show the code that you've used to configure SWRevealcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
                self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

to this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

is suposed that you  have a navigation controller of type`SWRevealViewController` with the segues `sw_front` to your `HomeViewController`or a NavigationController before it and a `sw_rear` to your menu VC. so you must instantiate the `SWRevealViewController` to show the menu, in your code your goint direct to your home screen so the `SWRevealViewController` is nil because is not been instantiate before the `HomeViewController`.

PD: here is a sample how i dit in a project and works out the box with the above code
[image]
and set this in the identity inspector
[image]

Comment: Your Explanation is correct and your code is not navigating to my home screen its staying in login screen only.....

Comment: have yo checked that the  code i posted is executed, print a stament in cosole to check is executed

Comment: I checked through Breakpoints its executing but Not navigating to home screen

Comment: check your swrevealviewcontrolelr implementation in storyboard because  si must navigate to homeviewcontroller is it been implemented correctly, i guess you dont have the ritght segue and that's why it not get to homeViewController

Comment: after successful login I am navigating screens using segue as for home sw_front & side menu sw_rear only and its working but the code you gave let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
is I didn't created any that type of identifier

Comment: but you should, how then your open the `SWRevealViewController` from code is it in Storyboard, i recomend you to set Storyboard Id to SWRevealViewController or to whaterver strign you like that not been used and then instantiate that viewcontroller.

Comment: I have edited my question Same like yours only and correct me if I am wrong

Comment: that code is suposed to be in appDelegate, why did you make a new instance of UIWindow since is a singleton across the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi storyboard concept.

1. Login Storyboard
2. Home Storyboard

   ```
   +(void) LoginHomeScreen:(NSString*)strController andIndex:(int)index 
   { 
        NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:USERDETAILS];

        NSDictionary *userData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

        if (userData != NULL && [userData count] > 0) {
            //DashboardVC
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuNavigationVC"];
            [navigationController setViewControllers:@[[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:strController]]];

            LGSideMenuController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
            mainViewController.rootViewController = navigationController;

            UIViewController * SideMenu = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuVC"];
            mainViewController.leftViewController = SideMenu;
            mainViewController.leftViewPresentationStyle = LGSideMenuPresentationStyleSlideBelow;

            UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window;
            window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

            [UIView transitionWithView:window duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:nil completion:nil];

        } else {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            LoginVC *loginVC = (LoginVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
            UINavigationController *navLogin = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
            navLogin.navigationBar.hidden = true;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window setRootViewController:navLogin];
        }
   }
   ```